# external libraries in FreeFem ++

Tags: c++, freefem++

We are talking about FreeFem++ (based on C++).
I need to calculate the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a matrix (stored in a bidimensional array) that it is created from a internal calculus, not created from bilinear form. Then I would to use an external function (then external library) that it can calucate a vector of eigenvalue and matrix that contains the eigenvector as a column.
In a FreeFem documentation there are examples that involves  I do not find technical support for this part.